# How to get all the metrics via Metrics Servlet in JSON format (as in Web UI) from Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, metrics

The apache Spark web UI gives a ton of useful information about the workers, driver, storage etc. But the Metrics Servlet gives only a few information. For eg, I get the following from /metrics/json :

```
{
  "version":"3.0.0",
  "gauges":{
    "local-1431683138663.<driver>.BlockManager.disk.diskSpaceUsed_MB":{
      "value":0
    },
    "local-1431683138663.<driver>.BlockManager.memory.maxMem_MB":{
      "value":3179
    },
    "local-1431683138663.<driver>.BlockManager.memory.memUsed_MB":{
      "value":169
    },
    "local-1431683138663.<driver>.BlockManager.memory.remainingMem_MB":{
      "value":3009
    },
    "local-1431683138663.<driver>.DAGScheduler.job.activeJobs":{
      "value":1
    },
    "local-1431683138663.<driver>.DAGScheduler.job.allJobs":{
      "value":1
    },
    "local-1431683138663.<driver>.DAGScheduler.stage.failedStages":{
      "value":0
    },
    "local-1431683138663.<driver>.DAGScheduler.stage.runningStages":{
      "value":1
    },
    "local-1431683138663.<driver>.DAGScheduler.stage.waitingStages":{
      "value":0
    }
  },
  "counters":{
  },
  "histograms":{
  },
  "meters":{
  },
  "timers":{
  }
}
```

How do I get other metrics like storage etc.?

Comment: There are other metrics for storage available here: http://server-url:port/api/v1/applications/[app-id]/storage/rdd Find all the api's here under "REST API"
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Comment: Thanks Thomas, These were added to spark Monitoring REST APIs in version 1.4. At the time of posting this question, these data were not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the data is now available in Spark Monitoring REST API from version 1.4 onwards. Thanks Apache Spark!

Link : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api